# application express web service - enable RESTFul Service

Tags: apex

I´m working on applicatin express 4.2.1.00.08. I would like to create a web service via the "Enable RESTful Access" field, but it wont show up. The "Enable RESTful Services" field under "Set Workspace Preferences" is set to "Yes" and i started a new application (page is set to "Page Is Public"). Do i need to install the APEX Listener for having access to that field?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the APEX Listener (now called 'Oracle REST Data Services') is necessary for RESTful Services.

[Download and Install Oracle Application Express Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/install.42/e35123/otn_install.htm#HTMIG505)

You also need to configure your installation of APEX to enable the APEX_LISTENER and APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER users in your DB.

[Configure RESTful Services](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/install.42/e35123/otn_install.htm#BABFGHFJ)

These steps are also described in [this Blog post](http://anandbitra.blogspot.nl/2013/11/installing-oracle-application-express-42.html) by Anand Bitra.